# Understanding Canjs Control sample

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-control, canjs-map

Am looking at the Canjs Sample for Control.

```
TaskStriker = can.Control({
    "{task} completed": function(){
        this.update();
    },
    update: function(){
        if ( this.options.task.completed ) {
            this.element.addClass( 'strike' );
        } else {
            this.element.removeClass( 'strike' );
        }
    }
});
var taskstriker = new TaskStriker({ 
    task: new Task({ completed: 'true' }) 
});
```

In this case what is the **Task object** exactly?. I tried creating the Task with the can.Construct but it is not triggering the update function when value is changed.

Can some one please explain a bit on this?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can.Construct does not implement observable properties.

The task object will be a can.Map (http://canjs.com/docs/can.Map.html) or a can.Model (http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.html). With those two you are able to observe changes on the object and thus trigger the update code.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things stand out: (1) Your task object is having `completed` set before `taskstriker` is initialized; and (2) to instantiate a can.Control or one of its subclasses, you need to pass in a DOM element as the first argument, and the options object as the second.

Comment: This is the example given in the canjs page.Please reffer the link below
http://canjs.com/docs/can.Control.prototype.on.html

Comment: The docs are incorrect on this. Go report it at https://github.com/bitovi/canjs.com/issues -- meanwhile here's an example that works:  http://jsfiddle.net/air_hadoken/mXzD7/1/

Comment: one more small question.So what happens when we do this step

can.Observe.extend("Task"). You haven't defined this object Task rt?. So what happens here ?.Can you please explain that as well.

Comment: That line is defining the Task class as a subclass of can.Observe.  It creates <root>.Task as a constructor function with no additional static or prototype properties over what can.Observe already has.